# How to modify Katalon report?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

[image: Reports]

I have generated a test suite and run the testng.xml file and default report is generated accordingly.

I want to modify default generated report. I want to display one column which shows the pass and fail result for each testcase. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment. It has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314797/how-to-configure-the-test-suite-collection-report-in-katalon-studio), as well.