# How to configure the Test suite Collection Report in Katalon Studio?

Tags: automation, katalon-studio

While configuring the Test suite collection, we will add the profile information for each test suite. Is it possible to add 'Profile' column to the Test suite Collection Report and also to the Exported HTML of Test suite Collection?

My TestSuiteCollection looks like:
[Test Suite Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMbd6.png)

My TestSuite Collection Report looks like:
[Test Suite Collection Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSzoy.png)

Is there any way to add this 'Profile' column to Report?

Comment: I don't think it can be done using Katalon Studio options. But, it can be coded in groovy as a custom reporting tool. Why don't you suggest it to Katalon [team](https://forum.katalon.com/categories/katalon-studio-feature-suggestions)?